# Connect geom_line only between specified factors

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I have a dataset that has diameter values for 4 treatment groups for several different months. I am plotting `Diameter ~ Treatment` for each month, as well as the `Diameter changes between months ~ Treatment`.

**Dataset looks like this:**

```
# the data that contains diameter for each month and diameter differences between months

> head(gatheredDiameterAndTreatmentData)
  Treatment             Month Diameter
1  Aux_Drop Diameter_mm.Sep01    55.88
2 Aux_Spray Diameter_mm.Sep01    63.50
3      DMSO Diameter_mm.Sep01    66.04
4     Water Diameter_mm.Sep01    43.18
5  Aux_Drop Diameter_mm.Sep01    38.10
6 Aux_Spray Diameter_mm.Sep01    76.20


# data that contains mean diameter and mean diameter changes for each month

> head(subMeansDiameter)
  Treatment             Month  Diameter   SEdiam
1  Aux_Drop   Diameter_mm.Dec  83.63857 29.62901
2  Aux_Drop Diameter_mm.Feb01 101.20923 24.84024
3  Aux_Drop Diameter_mm.Feb02 110.00154 22.51364
4  Aux_Drop   Diameter_mm.Jan  93.00308 25.13485
5  Aux_Drop   Diameter_mm.Mar 116.84000 22.19171
6  Aux_Drop Diameter_mm.Nov01  74.50667 17.40454
```

**Here is my code:**

```
# assign the factors name to pick
factorsOnXaxis.DiameterByMonth = c(
    "Diameter_mm.Sep01", "DiameterDiff.Sep01ToDec", "Diameter_mm.Dec", "DiameterDiff.DecToMar", "Diameter_mm.Mar")

# assign name to above factors
factorsOnXaxisName = c('Sep','Dec-Sep','Dec', 'Mar-Dec', 'Mar')    


# start plotting 
gatheredDiameterAndTreatmentData  %>%
  subset(Diameter != "NA") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = factor(Month), y = Diameter)) + 
  geom_point(aes(colour = Treatment), na.rm = TRUE, 
             position = position_dodge(width = 0.2)) +
  geom_point(data = subMeansDiameter, size = 4, aes(colour = Treatment), 
             na.rm = TRUE, position = position_dodge(width = 0.2)) +

  theme_bw() + # remove background 

  # add custom color to the "Treatment" levels 
  scale_colour_manual( 
    values = c("Aux_Drop" = "Purple", "Aux_Spray" = "Red", 
               "DMSO" = "Orange", "Water" = "Green")) + 

  # rearrange the x-axis
  scale_x_discrete(limits = factorsOnXaxis.DiameterByMonth, labels = factorsOnXaxisName) +

  # to connect the "subMeans - Diameter" values across time points
  geom_line(data = subMeansDiameter, aes(
    x = Month, y = Diameter, group = Treatment, colour = Treatment), 
    position = position_dodge(width = 0.2))
```

Which gives me a plot like this:

[image]

Instead of `geom_line` connecting line for each time points I want the line to be joined between specified x-axis factors, i.e

1. between Sep, Dec, March
2. between Dec-Sep to Mar-Dec

**I tried to manipulate the code line that uses `geom_line` as:**

```
geom_line(data = subMeansDiameter, aes(
    x = c("DiameterDiff.Sep01ToDec", "DiameterDiff.DecToMar"), y = Diameter, group = Treatment, colour = Treatment), 
    position = position_dodge(width = 0.2))
```

to connect the line between `Dec-Sep` to `Mar-Dec`.

But, this is not working. How can I change my code?

**Here is the data file I stores as *.tsv.**

gatheredDiameterAndTreatmentData = http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=38251290073324236098

subMeans = http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=93947954496987393129

Comment: add a group aesthetic

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper : please provide a code.

Answer (score 2):

Here you need to define groups explicitly as color is not enough.

Your example is not reproducible but here's something that will give you the idea, here's a plot with no explicit group:

```
ggplot(iris,aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length, color = Species)) + geom_line()
```

[image]

And now here's one with a group aesthetic, I have split the data using `Sepal.Length`'s values but you'll most likely use an `ifelse` deending on the month :

```
ggplot(iris,aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length, color = Species, 
                group = interaction(Species, Sepal.Length > 5.5))) + 
  geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I saw another example that used interaction. I will have to check how I can apply `interaction` method for my purpose. Btw, I uploaded the whole data as text file and have shared it with the question. Could you give a look now ?

Comment: interaction builds a unique id for every existing combination, the idea is to have a group for each combination of color (i.e. Species) and "is or not > 5.5"

Comment: I get "subMeansDiameter not found", I suggest you make a succint reproducible example that doesn't require external data, or ask anything you don't get about the present answer.